# Impresión en consola de resultado

Tags: java, sintaxis

Al ejecutar

```
System.out.println("Precio de venta para "+p.getNombre()  + p.getVenta());
```

da por salida

```
Precio de venta para Gaseosa139
```

Pero quisiera que salga por pantalla

```
Precio de venta para Gaseosa: 139
```

Comment: Intentaste poner:
System.out.println("Precio de venta para "+p.getNombre()  + ": " + p.getVenta());
?

Comment: String formato = "%1$-"+size+"s";
String.format(formato,cadena);-->https://innovaskynet.blogspot.com/2014/12/agregar-espacios-de-relleno-un-string_19.html

Answer (score 1):

Eso ocurre porque no has tenido en cuenta ni los dos puntos ni la separación. Puedes añadir ambos en una cadena de caracteres, establecida por las comillas.

```
System.out.println("Precio de venta para " + p.getNombre() + ": " + p.getVenta());
```

Así debería salir como quieres. Un saludo.

Comment: Genio, muchisimas Gracias.

Comment: De nada! Me alegra haberte ayudado.